# How to download SP.UI.Dialog.js?

Tags: modal-dialog

I have got same Modal Dialog on Sharepoint 2010. If I tried to migrate to Sharepoint 2013 I must download SP.UI.Dialog.js How Could I do it ?

Comment: why do you need to download?

Comment: Because i Must run modal Dialogs windows on Sharepoint 2013

Comment: Well it's a part of 2013 too, so no need to download it. You will need to use `SP.SOD.executeFunc` to load the script

Comment: But how Robert ?

Comment: You can see it here for example: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149708/sp-ui-modal-dialog-pop-up-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1):

I managed this by this two line of code:

```
<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
```

```
<input style="margin-left:155px;" id="Button2" type="button" value="Zamknij okno dialogowe"  onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, 'Ok clicked'); return false;" />
```